# Eclipse Scout get Desktop on page

Tags: desktop, eclipse-scout

I am looking for a way to get current Desktop() inside page.

I know I have `getOutline()`, but I need Desktop().

Is there a way to get it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- The session know the desktop
- The current thread (the scout job that is running) knows the session

Here is one possibility that is working anywhere in the Scout model code:

```
ClientSyncJob.getCurrentSession().getDesktop()
```